# vue3 composition API - watch

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

I am trying to get to grips with the composition API. Struggling with watch:

```js
const totalValuation = ref(0);
const values = ref([1, 2, 3]);
totalValuation.value = watch(finalTasksFiltered.value, () => {
  return values.value.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  console.log(prev + curr);
  return prev + curr;
  }, 0);
});
  
return {
  finalTasksFiltered,
  totalValuation,
};
```

The console.log works exactly like it should ***(1,3,6)*** but I cannot seem to render it to the DOM.
When I check to console it is fine but in the DOM like so {{ totalValuation }} it returns:

```
() => { (0,_vue_reactivity__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.stop)(runner); if (instance) { (0,_vue_shared__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.remove)(instance.effects, runner); } }
```

Oh, I am using Quasar - not sure if that makes a difference.

I am sure its something small.

I have imported ref and watch from vue.
I have a computed function working fine too.

Answer (score 1):

`watch` is meant to execute a function when some value changes. It is not meant to be assigned as a ref. What you're looking to do seems like a better fit for `computed`

**watch:** (no assignment)

```js
watch(finalTasksFiltered.value, () => {
  totalValuation.value = values.value.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  console.log(prev + curr);
  return prev + curr;
  }, 0);
});
```

**computed:** (uses assignment)

```js
const totalValuation = computed(() => {
  return values.value.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    console.log(prev + curr);
    return prev + curr;
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Computed gives me a result of 0[object Object]. The console gives me the same result. It appears to be an improvement but not the solution

Comment: I get the following warning: [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 32ms

Comment: looks like something else might be happening here. that code, on it's own should be working. a forced reflow error sounds like something is stuck in a loop